# How to read in Chinese text and write Chinese characters to csv - Python 3

Tags: python

I've searched SO but have not been able to find the answer to this specific problem. I am trying to read in from a .txt file of Chinese characters. When I try to write to a .csv, the contents of cells look like this:

b'\xef\xbb\xbf\xe5'

as opposed to:

山西襄汾

How can I output to a .csv the latter format? Snippet of relevant code is below:

```
infilehandle = open(infilepath, encoding = 'utf-8') # open .txt file
txtlines = infilehandle.read().replace('\n', '')
date_pattern = re.compile('(\d{4}.\d{1,2}.\d{1,2})')
date = date_pattern.findall(txtlines)[0]
title = txtlines.split(date)[0]
localrow = []
localrow.append(date.encode("utf-8-sig"))
localrow.append(title.encode("utf_8_sig"))
outfilehandle.writerow(localrow) # writes to .csv
```

Comment: Was `outfilehandle` also created with `encoding='utf-8'`?

Comment: If data items for `writerow` aren't strings, they are converted with `str` but `str(b'n') == "b'n'"`

Comment: How are you viewing the contents of the `.csv` file?

Comment: Your snippet of code is not so relevant as you say it is. It seems to search for a sequence of digits and do something with them. Are you sure that is an important part of your problem?

Comment: Peter, I am viewing the contents in Excel. I use the default to set outfilehandle, which I believe in Python 3 is utf-8 but I could be wrong.

Comment: Michael, what would be a potential solution to stop writerow from converting to str?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, make sure to create `outfilehandle` with `encoding='utf-8'`, as suggested by [Peter Wood](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53309456/how-to-read-in-chinese-text-and-write-chinese-characters-to-csv-python-3#comment93499784_53309456), like so:

```
outfilehandle = csv.writer(open('outfile.csv', 'w', encoding='utf-8'))
```

Then there is no need to call `date.encode("utf-8-sig")`, just change lines 7-8 in your code snippet into:

```
localrow.append(date)
localrow.append(title)
```

Also, it may be helpful to read [Python Unicode HOWTO](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/unicode.html) and [Processing Text Files in Python 3](http://python-notes.curiousefficiency.org/en/latest/python3/text_file_processing.html).

Comment: I modified my code, but the resulting cell contents now look like: å±±è¥¿è instead of the Chinese characters in the input text file. I have read through the links provided, but am unsure how to apply that information to writing to a csv. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Realizing this is an Excel issue. Opening the file in Notepad displays the "correct" characters.

Comment: @steven.m787 you may need to change Excel's encoding. see this: https://www.itg.ias.edu/content/how-import-csv-file-uses-utf-8-character-encoding-0